# Seaborn scatterplot legend not showing

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to plot some data with the following code

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, centers=10, cluster_std=1.0, center_box=(-10.0, 10.0), shuffle=True, random_state=None)

palette = np.array(sns.color_palette("bright", 10))  #Chossing color  
sns.scatterplot(X[:,0],X[:,1],legend='full',c=palette[y])
```

[image]

The color is beautiful, but the legend is missing.
When I check the documentation, I see:

> How to draw the legend. If “brief”, numeric **`hue`** and **`size`** variables
>   ....

So it seems I also need to include the `hue` argument.
But when I try the `hue` argument with the following codes, the following graph is created instead...

```
sns.scatterplot(X[:,0],X[:,1],legend='full',hue=y,c=palette[y])
```

[image]

The legend is showing, but the color is not what I want. After adding the `hue` argument, it seems it overwrite the palette argument. No matter what palette I choose, the color is still ugly as hell...

**My question is:**
How to show legend while maintaining the color that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use the `palette` kwarg, and specify the hues with your `y` values.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, centers=10, cluster_std=1.0,
                  center_box=(-10.0, 10.0), shuffle=True, random_state=None)

palette = sns.color_palette("bright", 10)  #Choosing color
sns.scatterplot(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], palette=palette, hue=y, legend='full')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So, I mixed up with the `c` kwarg for matplotlib scatter plot with the seaborn `palette` kwarg? Now it works, thanks.